# How could I generate proper tags file for the c source as below using ctags?

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

I am using Exuberant Ctags v5.8 and the C source sample that I would like to generate tags file from is as below, thanks!

```
#define PACK(x) __packed x                                                                                                                                                                                  

typedef PACK(struct) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} my_struct;

PACK(void *) my_func(PACK(void *) var1, int var2)
{
    *var1 = var2;
    return var1;
}
```

And this is the contents of generated tag file:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/ 
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/ 
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/ 
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME Exuberant Ctags  // 
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/ 
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8 // 
PACK    test.c  /^#define PACK(/;"  d   file: 
PACK    test.c /^typedef PACK(struct) {$/;" f
```

while my expected contents of tag file should be as following:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8 //
a   test.c  /^    int a;$/;"    m   struct:__anon1  file:
b   test.c  /^    int b;$/;"    m   struct:__anon1  file:
c   test.c  /^    int c;$/;"    m   struct:__anon1  file:
my_func test.c  /^void * my_func(void * var1, int var2)$/;" f
my_struct   test.c  /^} my_struct;$/;"  t   typeref:struct:__anon1  file:
```

How can I get the latter tag file from original C source file? Thanks!

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey please check my update in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the only thing I can think of is to do some preprocessing, e.g. with AWK into a parallel directory tree replacing PACK(x) with x.  Run ctags on the parallel tree.  Exuberant ctags uses relative paths, so you can just move the tags file back into the original directory tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done directly without preprocessing the files yourself (e.g. with awk, as I commented above) and having Exuberant Ctags operate on the preprocessed version.

Exuberant Ctags uses the -I [command line option](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html#OPTIONS) to handle defines.  It allows you to ignore preprocessor defines (e.g `-I PACK`), do substitution of defines (e.g. `-I PACK=FOO`), and it allows you to ignore the identifier and its argument list (e.g. `-I PACK+`), but none of these options handle replacing the macro with one of its arguments.

You might consider requesting this as a new feature, but it doesn't appear to be actively developed anymore.  The last revision was in July 2009.